# Custom route in Code Igniter being overwritten

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have these routes:

```
$route['shop/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/category_listing/$1/$2';
$route['shop/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/product_listing/$1/$2/$3';
```

When I call this url:

http://mysite.com/shop/mens/trainers/a-product

the product_listing method should be called but instead the first method (category_listing) gets called and product_listing is never invoked.

How can I make this work as required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Order of array elements matters!**

Keyword `(:any)` matches everything, even slashes, so in your example CodeIgniter finds the first matching route and doesn't look any further.

So, if we do like this:

```
$route['shop/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/product_listing/$1/$2/$3';
$route['shop/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/category_listing/$1/$2';
```

...then product listing is matched first, then everything else.

Even more, you can use regular expressions (e.g. `([a-z0-9]+)`) to create rules you need.

Comment: +1 `:any` also matches a slash.  That's why flipping those two is the way to go.

Comment: FYI, in CI 3.0+, `:any` will no longer match a slash.